# Can I calculate the other sides of a rectangle triangle if I know the hypotenuse and that the other sides are positive integers?

Tags: geometry

I know that if the sides are not integers, then the equation has infinite solutions, but what about if the solutions can only be positive integers? Thanks.

Comment: Sadly, no.  Consider the triples $(\sqrt {50},5,5)$ and $(\sqrt {50},7,1)$

Comment: Is the hypotenuse given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can not.

Consider the triples $(\sqrt {50},5,5)$ and $(\sqrt {50},7,1)$.

If you want all three to be integers, then consider $(65,16,63), (65,33,56)$

Comment: Just a note onto this answer: there might be more than one choice for the side lengths (even in the positive integers), but there are finitely many (for instance, in the example with $65$, we know each of the legs are one of $1,2,\cdots 64$, narrowing it down to finitely many possibilities).